# Stay focus in a field when field still empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have two input fields there are "Phone" field and "Name" field. I want cursor stay focus in "Phone" field when its still empty. Because when i click "tab" when field empty, the alert appears and after I click OK cursor move to "Name" field. How to make cursor stay focus on "Phone" if it still empty?

There is my code :

```
    function whenEmpty(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        alert("Please fill the field.");
    }
    return false;
    }
```

When I call the function :

```
<tr>
<td><div class="required"><label>Phone</label></div></td>
<td><form:input path="connote.shipperPhone" id="shipperPhone" name="shipperPhone"
onchange="loadCustomerData()" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;" onblur="whenEmpty(this);"
htmlEscape="true" size="20" maxlength="50" tabindex="3"/> <form:errors
path="connote.shipperPhone" cssClass="error" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to change little bit:

```
function whenEmpty(field) {
   if (field.value == '') {
      alert("Please fill the field.");
      field.focus(); // <----add this to focus
      return false; // <-----move this in case of blank field only.
   }
}
```

Comment: you have `onchange/onblur` together instead you can use unobtrusively.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I found the answer of my own question. I changed it :

```
function whenEmpty(field) {
       if (field.value == '') {
          alert("Please fill the field.");
          field.focus();
       }  
    }
```

Comment: but before it i don't see that hahahaha please forgive me :v